How to capture redirect url upon navigation using playwright in javascript?
Using Playwright I need to capture the initial url a new tab is opened with, before redirection.
These are the steps implemented:

click a certain element that will cause a new tab/window to open
the new tab will be opened with a intermediary url that will immediately redirect to the final destination
compare the redirect url (not the final destination) with a reference string

Here is my code:
const el = page.locator('div#clickable_element');
const requestMap = [];

page.on('popup', request => {
  requestMap.push(request.url());
});

await el.click();
await page.waitForTimeout(3000);

const testUrl = 'https://www.example.com';
await expect(requestMap.includes(testUrl)).toBe(true);

Here I'm using the popup event, as this is the one that is fired upon opening a new tab. I tried the request event too, with no success. Unfortunately, the request.url() only contains the string of the final destination, not the original url that was used to open the new tab. Thus requestMap.includes(testUrl) returns false.
I had a look around in the request object, but could not find any reference to the redirect url.
How, or where can I access to the original/redirect url? Thank you!

await page.waitForTimeout(3000); shouldn't be necessary

A [mcve] of the site would be great.
